Why won't Matplotlib's imshow plot 0.5 as grey?
I remember this working.  Zero meant fully dark and one meant fully lit up and in-between meant some shade of grey for plotting with pyplot.imshow.  I remember plotting the MNIST data of handwritten digits like that.  I wrote the following,
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


matrix = 0.5*np.identity(5)
plt.imshow(matrix, cmap='grey')
plt.show()

If I do not multiply the identity matrix with a half, I get what I expect.  But--multiplying it with a half, I expected to see greys along the diagonal.  However, it still plots whites there.
Am I missing some small detail?  Is there a way to get the behaviour that I expect?

@jared was there a reason for the edit to the import statement? I thought the one before edit was preferred.

Your statement worked but I changed it to a more standard format.

You probably want this -
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


matrix = 0.5*np.identity(5)
plt.imshow(matrix, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.show()

It looks like your program is defaulting to a vmax of 0.5 (and makes the value of 0.5 essentially identical to values of 1) when the inputs is 0.5 identity matrix, setting the bounds seems to fix that issue

I see. Was the behaviour always like this or did this change recently?

@scribe I do not know, I just did some debugging with some testing based on the outputs

@scribe Always like that, the documentation under the norm parameter states: "By default, a linear scaling is used, mapping the lowest value to 0 and the highest to 1."

And under the vmin, vmax parameters: "By default, the colormap covers the complete value range of the supplied data."
